# n keys question: probability by chain rule vs naive counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is the following problem:

> A person has $n$ keys out of which only one is correct (can open the door). She tries the keys one by one at random and if the key chosen is incorrect, put it back (so that it can be chosen again). What is the probability that the right key is found on the $5th$ attempt?

It can be easily solved using chain rule and the idea that all attempts have the same probabilities for incorrect and correct keys, so:
$$
P(E) = \frac{(n-1)^4}{n^4} \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{(n - 1)^4}{n^5}    
$$

I looked at the result and seems that it is completely equivalent to the following experiment:

> Pick 5 keys at random **with replacement** and calculate probability of event where the correct key was only in the last 5th choice.

Sample space of this new experiment is simple and all outcomes are equally likely to occur, so we can calculate the probability of the given event just by counting. $|S| = n^5$ and $|E| = (n - 1)^4$, so:
$$
P(E) = \frac{(n - 1)^4}{n^5}
$$

But I can't understand intuitively why these experiments are equivalent. In the original experiment the person will stop on any attempt when she finds the right key, but in new experiment a person always picks $5$ keys. Intuitively it doesn't matter what the person will choose after she finds the right key before 5th attempt, but we include such cases in new experiment when calculating the cardinality of sample space, so I am confusing.

Could someone please give an intuition why these experiments are equivalent (if they are of course) and how one can derive it from seeing the original problem?

Comment: Adding the rule that the second experimenter gives up after five tries doesn't change the result of any trial.  Either you get four fails then a success, or you don't.  Phrased differently, to determine if a trial is a Win or a Loss, you only need to look at the first five moves.

Comment: Both calculations  look like "probability of failing $4$ times then succeeding on the next attempt" so give the same probability.  A different approach would be "probability of failing four times minus probability of failing five times", i.e. $\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^4- \left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^5$, and this also gives the same result since you cannot fail five times without initially failing four times.